# How to Select Date Range using RegEx

Tags: regex

I have date strings that looks like so:

```
20120817110329
```

Which, as you can see, is formatted: YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

How would I select (using RegEx) dates that are between 7/15 and 8/20? Or what about 8/1 to 8/15?

I have this working if I want to select a range that doesn't involve more than one place, but it is very limited:

```
^2012081[0-7] //selects 8/10 to 8/17
```

**Update**

Never forget the obvious (as pointed out by Wiseguy below), one can simply look for a range between 201207150000 and 201208209999.

Comment: Why does it have to be regex? Regex isn't always the right tool for the job.

Comment: I'm using MongoDB. This is the way the date is stored on a particular obj.

Comment: The better solution would be to convert all these to actual MongoDB date objects.

Comment: @mckeed, indeed. If this current project were bigger in scope, it would warrant the extra work. For now, I'm just running a one-off report for some data I'm interested in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're just querying a database field that contains these values, you could simply check for a value between `201207150000` and `201208209999`.

---

If you still want the regex, it ain't pretty, but this does it:

```
^20120(7(1[5-9]|2\d|3[01])|8([0-1]\d|20))\d{4}$
```

*[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/DdlVaC/1)*

You basically have to account for each possible range by hand.

```
^20120
(
7
  (
    1[5-9]
   |2\d
   |3[01]
  )
 |
8
  (
    [0-1]\d
   |20
  )
)
\d{4}$
```

Comment: @doremi I had a thought. If you're just querying a database field that contains these values, could you simply check for a value between `201207150000` and `201208209999`?

Comment: Actually, in this case, you're right, I can query the range. Thanks! P.S. The regex is still useful. Thanks^2.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
^2012(07(1[5-9]|[2-3][0-9])|08([0-1][0-9]|20))
```

Although the other answers are pretty the same...
You can check [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html) for more info.